# Implementing the AWS load balancer controller in front of my nginx ingress controller

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress

I've been using the Nginx ingress Controller which used to provision a classic load balancer with TCP listeners but we now want to move to ALBs due to http/https listeners.

My idea is that I still keep the nginx ingress Controller inside the cluster but I add an aws load balancer controller on top of it which should create an ALB and handle the traffic until it reaches the ALB.

My only issue is I can't find good enough examples of how to achieve this
Is this a reasonable setup?
How can I achieve this using both ingress controllers

Comment: Why do you want to switch to an ALB? You can use the AWS Load Balancer Controller to provision a NLB. With an NLB, you can continue using the old "Service" paradigm for the NGINX ingress controller.

Comment: We want to switch to ALB because we want a better insight on our HTTP requests. We've had some issues lately with 502 errors and we want to be able to check the access logs of our LB to find the culprit. For that I believe we need an ALB instead because the NLB logs are not enough

Comment: I see. An NLB will be more performant than an ALB, but if that is not a concern than the ALB is fine.

Comment: I think you'll find what you're looking for here, https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/exposing-kubernetes-applications-part-3-nginx-ingress-controller/

Comment: @JeremyCowan thanks a lot for the pointers, that helped me go in the right direction because I realized I don't necessarily need the aws load balancer controller too, I just need an ALB

Comment: still not a bad idea to use the load balancer controller with the nginx ingress controller. you don't have to use it for all your ingress objects. you only use it for ingress to the nginx ingress controller. if you're concerned about the consumption of cluster resources, then i guess you can go without the load balancer controller.

Answer (score 1):

How is the nginx setup? Is it EC2 instances with auto-scaling group? If so, you can add the auto-scaling group or the IP addresses of the EC2s as a target group for the ALB and that should work. You can also perform TLS termination on ALB. The setup is almost same as CLB except you use https or http instead of TCP.

Comment: Nginx is setup via the nginx ingress Controller helm chart on our EKS cluster. That is the nginx pods and the nginx service on our Kubernetes cluster